# Does Jar-Jar have some Force ability?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, jar-jar-binks

It seems that Jar-Jar has some very lucky breaks during the battle of Naboo. Is it possible that he has some innate hidden Force ability?

Comment: Who is Jar-Jar Binks? I don't remember this character in the Star Wars Saga.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris Then how did you know his last name? I don't think I mentioned it in my question. :)

Comment: @xecaps12 Use the Force, OghamaOsiris did.

Comment: Lucas forced us to watch him, isn't that enough?

Comment: Jar Jar is NOT a Jedi...or a Time Lord.

Comment: In my opinion, Jar-Jar is a _shlemeil_.  He even says in the -3rd movie TPM, that he was exiled due to his clumsiness. (Footnote: The One True first movie was Star Wars ANH.)

Comment: EW, EW, EW, EEEEEEEEEWWWWWWWWW!!!! I vote for an immediate deletion! Why oh God WHY bring that ghastly creature up again?

Comment: I really understood the hate for Jar Jar when I saw the english version of the film. In the german version his voice isn't nearly as annoying as in the english version. This took away some of the pain =)

Comment: I have a bad feeling about this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Out-of-universe answer: Jar-Jar's war antics were clearly done for comic effect to entertain the kiddies.  I think the [Accidental Aiming Skills](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AccidentalAimingSkills) trope applies.

In-universe: I don't see how we could come to any other conclusion; Jar-Jar must have innate Force-related abilities.  Anakin's amazing luck in the fighter in *Phantom Menace* when he didn't know what he was doing seemed exactly like Jar-Jar's luck earlier in the film.  In fact a Reddit user wrote a [brilliant defense of the Jar-Jar Binks character](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWars/comments/3qvj6w/theory_jar_jar_binks_was_a_trained_force_user/) as an obvious Force-adept and perhaps the true Phantom Menace of the first movie.

Comment: The scene with Anakin is what I was thinking of when I asked.

Comment: Jar-Jar was Qui-Gon Jinn's backup plan if the kid didn't make it through the pod race.

Comment: @Chahk - They were going to try to sell him as food, hopefully.

Comment: Jar-Jar invented the ability "Force Annoy".

Comment: More like "Sap the will to live after seeing me in the movies" force ability. This ability is exponentially more powerful than anything Sidious ever had!!

Comment: Brilliant defense indeed!

Answer (score 4):

There's actually a whole discussion of Jar Jar possibly being a Sith lord, and some hints that Lucas had a much more important role for him in mind until the negative reactions got him to back off the character. I believe the good people at Cracked summed the issue up wonderfully in the following video:

[Why Jar Jar Binks Is More Evil Than You Ever Knew - Cracked Responds](https://youtu.be/2Z7jq1uCnNU)

Comment: You could try to add some quotes or a transcript of the video to make your answer even stronger.

Answer (score -1):

Jar Jar's clumsiness made his movements unpredictable, confusing the simplistic targeting software used by the battle droids.