# Who knew Yoda was on Dagobah?

Tags: star-wars, yoda

*Full Disclosure: I have only seen the seven movies.*

**Who all (if anyone) knew that Yoda was on Dagobah?**  I'm assuming Obi-Wan only knew, because he was a ghost.

[Edit: This will be followed up with a question about Dagobah and its mention/role in stories outside of the movies; therefore the answer should be about characters considered relevant, knowing Yoda was on Degobah.]

[Edit: Anyone relevant; friend/foe or just knew of him before he went in hiding/exile.]

Comment: That thing in the bog that wanted to eat R2D2 probably knew as well.

Comment: Well... right haha.  I'll amend the question.

Comment: No need—I was just being a bit facetious. :-)

Comment: I know; I thought it was funny!

Comment: @Mikey you're asking two questions here. Please ask your question on the baddies laying claim to Dagobah separately. Every question description needs to be focused and wholly relevant to the question asked in the title.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - thanks, I've edited it to provide less broad scope.

Comment: It appeared that, at times, know Yoda did not.

Comment: "...because he was a ghost" - Yoda tells Obi-Wan he's going to Degobah at the end of RotS.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't gotten far enough yet to confirm, but [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52205/how-did-luke-know-where-to-land-on-dagobah) SciFi.SE question has comments and answers noting that R2-D2 traveled to Dagobah with Yoda in season 6 of the *Clone Wars* TV show, which is still canon in the Disney rehash. I don't know if that means R2-D2 knew Yoda was still there in *Empire Strikes Back*, but since his memory was never wiped, it's a distinct possibility.

Comment: see also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/53154/54827

Answer (score 1):

Obi-Wan probably knew it before he died. In Clone Wars Qui-Gon (as a ghost) spoke to Yoda and showed him the tree on Dagoba (where Luke fought Darth Vader hologram later). And as Kenobi used to talk to his former master, he might be told about that.

Comment: Given that Obi-wan told Luke specifically in _Episode V_: "You must go to the Dagobah system.  Seek Yoda", then it's pretty likely he knew ;)

Comment: @JaneS but that was after he died.

Comment: I still strongly suggest that Obi-wan knew before he died.